# Flink Streaming AsynchronousException{java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint for operator map -> sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

```
AsynchronousException{java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 3547 for operator MetricsMap -> Sink: MetricsMapSink (66/80).}
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:970)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 3547 for operator MetricsMap -> Sink: MetricsMapSink (66/80).
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to file:/nfsc/vol1/sma/ckdir/30aa873dd41d064436a05c0b3d0bcc75/chk-3547/cde53940-05bc-4ff8-a80e-5909faaefad3 in order to obtain the stream state handle
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FutureUtil.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtil.java:43)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:897)
    ... 5 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: Could not properly cancel managed keyed state future.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotResult.cancel(OperatorSnapshotResult.java:90)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.cleanup(StreamTask.java:1023)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:961)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to file:/nfsc/vol1/sma/ckdir/30aa873dd41d064436a05c0b3d0bcc75/chk-3547/cde53940-05bc-4ff8-a80e-5909faaefad3 in order to obtain the stream state handle
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.flink.util.FutureUtil.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtil.java:43)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateUtil.discardStateFuture(StateUtil.java:85)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotResult.cancel(OperatorSnapshotResult.java:88)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to file:/nfsc/vol1/sma/ckdir/30aa873dd41d064436a05c0b3d0bcc75/chk-3547/cde53940-05bc-4ff8-a80e-5909faaefad3 in order to obtain the stream state handle
```

Flink 1.3.2 use NAS for file storage

bug? same as the 7590?

how to trigger this problem?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7590

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flink version < 1.3.x
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7180. If possible please upgrade.